# Reshaping the particular dimension of matrix

Tags: linux, fortran

I am trying to reshape one of the dimension of matrix into 2d in fortran

I have a matrix "vfm[4208,5155]". Out of this, I want to convert "vfm[4208,1166:5515]" into "vfm[4208,290]".

EXtracting vfm[4208,1166:5515] makes it to vfm[4208,4350]. Further, I want to reshape a second dimension (4350) into 2d (290x15) and then average the reshaped matrix on its second dimension (15). It means final matrix should be as "vfm[4208,290]".

Here is a flow of code:
vfm[4208,4350] --> vfm[4208,290,15] ---> vfm[4208,290]

Actual code of mine is too long, thereofre I am writing a assocaited part of code here.

```
Character*80:vfmf
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable, target :: vfm
integer, dimension(:,:), pointer :: vfm1

xdim=4208
ydim=5515

open(16,file=vfmf,status='old')

allocate(vfm(xdim,ydim))

read(16,*)((vfm(ii,jj),jj=1,ydim),ii=1,xdim)

vfm1 => vfm(:,1166:5515)

vfm2=reshape((vfm1),(/xdim,4350/),(/xdim,290,15))

Stop
End
```

Following this I am facing following error

```
Error: Syntax error in array constructor at (1)
```

I am unable to reshape vfm[4208, 4350] to vfm[4208,290,15] using fortran in Ubuntu.

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us your code. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Sir, I edited my question and added a part of a code, as my original code is too long to post here. Thank you

Comment: You have the obvious syntax error missing a `/` in the array constructor (better to use `[...]` for this reason), but you also haven't declared `vfm2`.  Please correct those and we'll look at any other problems that follow.

Comment: Sir, i am not much familiar with fortran but I revised my syntax by adding ' / ' in the array constructor, but still I am having incompatible ranks error.  "Error: Incompatible ranks 1 and 2 in assignment at (1)"